# Find substrings by list of words in pandas string column of tweets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with a column `clean_tweets` which contains tweets (not split text, it's just the entire (string) text of tweets).

I also have a list of substrings (variable `raw_lst` below) and want to create a list (in a new column) which would include the occurrence of all the `raw_lst` substrings in each tweet (variable `intensityFinal` below).
I also want to make the code (1) allow the substrings to appear in any form (e.g., compensate, recompense, etc.) and(2) insensitive to the case of letter, so that it also picks, say, "Apolog" and "Compens" as well

My ultimate goal is to **have a column which indicates how many times the substrings in my `raw_lst` have appeared in each tweet**.

Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('tweets.csv')

raw_lst = ["apolog",
          "compens"]

df['intensityFinal'] = np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()

  
for element in raw_lst:
    df["intensity"]= df['tweets_clean'].str.findall(element) 
    pd.concat(["intensity", "intensityFinal"])

df["intensityLength"]= df['intensityFinal'].str.len()
print(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Your question never told us what you were analyzing: 'tweets_clean ' is not split text, it's just the entire (string) text of a tweet. Hence your title is more like *"Find substring match counts for each of a list of words in string column"*. And that's substring match, not exact match, so *'recompense', 'compensated'* etc. will all match. It's misleading when you say *'includes the occurrence of the dictionary words''* because your list *aren't* words, they're substrings/ word-fragments.

Comment: **What output do you want?** You first said your ultimate goal is counts of word-fragments/lemmatized words(?), but you use `.str.findall()`. There's a difference between *'recompense', 'compensated'*, but this code isn't going to pick it up. So why bother creating tons of intermediate columns with the actual substring matches, when you only want the counts? Please edit your question to say what ultimately you want.

Comment: ...and if your intent is lemmatized words, you need to match word-boundaries before your fragments, so you don't want `.str.findall()`, unless your regex has an assertion for start-of-word. (Or unless you first split the input on whitespace or punctuation, but that's more grief.)

Comment: @smci Thanks. These are all great points. I tried to clarify in my question. Does this make more sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join all values of list by `|` for regex or for extract values to new column:

```
df=pd.read_csv('tweets.csv')

raw_lst = ["apolog",
           "compens"]

df["intensityFinal"] = df['tweets_clean'].str.count('|'.join(raw_lst)) 

print (df)
```

EDIT: For extract only words `compens` and not `recompense` use word boundaries:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in raw_lst)
df["intensityFinal"] = df['tweets_clean'].str.count(pat)
```

Comment: The OP's title was very misleading so it had to be changed. Also, their code example wasn't going to pick up the difference between *'recompense', 'compensated'*. So, it depends do they want all the actual substring matches, or just a count?

Comment: @jezrael: but now you clobbered my edit to fit your code. Again, I pointed out that the OP's title disagrees with the body (they say they want counts), and gave the example  their code example wasn't going to pick up the difference between 'recompense', 'compensated'. OP needs to actually fix either the body, the code example, and/or the title.

Comment: @smci sorry for the confusion. I have extensively edited the body of my question.

Comment: @jezrael Can you kindly edit your response (if needed) in light of the changes I have made to the body of my question? Really appreciate it!

Comment: To make your code insensitive to letter case, can I update it as shown below?                 
        df["intensityFinal"]= df['tweets_clean'].str.count('|'.join(raw_lst), re.I)